# Regex will not matching a word

Tags: java, regex

Hy everyone,

i have a problem with regex. I would like to match all the words that start with 240 and end when matching 10 for the first time. The problem happens when 10 is repeat.I'm using this regex to solve this problem:

(^240+)(.*?10)

Unfortunatly for my date this regex is not support. For example my regex works with value of 240189102710437108 and extract correctly the date of 24018910 but does not work for the value of 240110102712237180 because the value is 1010. i Would like that the regex extract the value beetween 240 and 10 but get the last occurences of 10.

I hope you could help to solve this problem

Comment: `.*?` will match as few chars as possible, use `.*`

Comment: it does not work for 240189102710437108 . Your solution retrieve until 24018910271043710 i has to stop at 24018910

Comment: Then your `.*?` is already working as expected if you want to match as few as possible.

Comment: no it does not work if 10 is duplicated so i has to find an other solution. For example 240110102712237180, i want to retrieve until  24011010 but i've stop until 240110 if i use .*?

Comment: Ok, got it, you need `^240.*?(?:10)+`.

Comment: Does that answer your question correct?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like I’m channeling JWZ, this would probably be easier without regular expressions. `s.startsWith("240")` and `s.indexOf("10")` would be enough.